# Disable contract bytecode size warning in remix

Tags: contract-development, remix, contract-deployment

Remix warns me by highlighting the whole contract in Orange that i have exceeded the maximum contract size of 24KB.

I am developing a contract for a private network which does not impose this limit, so i would like to stop remix from warning me.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can enable optimization in the Solidity compiler in Remix IDE, if you want to deploy it through Remix IDE:

See: https://remix-ide.readthedocs.io/fr/latest/compile.html

Comment: Im not trying to work around the issue by reducing it by a few KB. I want remix to ignore the limit entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your **Solidity Compiler** tab, click on **Advanced Configurations**, and then check **"Enable Optimization"**. Make sure to leave the number at the default of 200.